# "Neo4j::MigrationError: Duplicate constraint for Person"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, neo4j, ruby-on-rails-5, neo4jrb

I created a new rails app using Neo4j,then created a Model/Node Person. 
But when i run rake neo4j:migrate it gives the error for Duplicate Constraint.

I have previously created another Rails app on the same machine with same Model/Node as a Person and both these are conflicting.

Both the apps use different HTTP port, I want to know how i can Create standalone DBs in Neo4j or alter the  storage Path, so that separate apps can have same Models.

Currently using same storage path for both apps 
i.e.
 config.neo4j.storage_path = "#{config.root}/db/share_portal/neo4j-#{Rails.env}"

Answer (score 0):

You need to run multuple instances of Neo4j, with different ports, so data do not overlap.

I used https://github.com/cohesivestack/ineo with http connection (I'm not sure if [bolt is supported](https://github.com/cohesivestack/ineo/issues/32))
Also nice way to run multiple neo4j servers is with https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j-rake_tasks

Comment: Ineo is active again. The last version (1.1.0), with support to bolt port, has been released today. github.com/cohesivestack/ineo